# How to pass column value as parameter for rolling or shift

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,1),columns = ['A'])
df['pos']=[0,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,3,4]
```

I try to

```
df.A.rolling(df['pos']).max()
or
df.A.shift(df['pos'])
```

It doesn't work, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, both the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) operations are sequence-to-sequence transformations. If you want to produce a series of sequences based on the integer parameters in `pos`, you need to repeat this operation:

```
pd.DataFrame({f'seq {i}': df.A.shift(i) for i in df.pos})
```